Is it okay to ask for a job description of my old job?
I had a full time job while studying at my university. Now I'm about to finish my studies and I could use this work experience as the mandatory internship required.
The problem is that I need a job description issued by the employer for the universtity to evaluate if it's acceptable or not... and I don't have it saved.
Is it okay to ask my former employer for a job description of my old position? And who should I reach out to if so?
Edit: The job description should be issued and certified by my former employer.

Of course it's ok to ask. You'll be asking for a favour, but it's a small one. Drop your contact at the employer (probably your manager) a note like this:

I really enjoyed working at Company and I learned (or grew or whatever) a lot. Now it seems that I can get credit for an internship as well, as long as I get a job description that the university can evaluate. Can you provide me with one or tell me who I should ask?

If you know where the details of this internship program are, include a link to that so that whoever is helping you understands what is required.
Close with some thanks, and should you wish to ever work there again, some mild expression of that wish. You might get a reply with the description you want, or a suggestion of who to email instead. Ideally you would not get a reply with questions because you would have provided all the details, but if you do get questions, answer them promptly. Express thanks in each email and stay polite and friendly at all times, so that people enjoy working with you on this little administrative detail you need help with.

Thanks for your answer I'm going to reach out.

@Bilbo perhaps you could combine this suggestion with XavierJ's. Create your job description based on what you believe your job duties were, and then send that in your email to your old manager, asking them to confirm or update it as appropriate. That may feel like less of an ask from them and make it more likely that you'll get a useful response.

Yes you can reach out to them, probably your former direct supervisor or anyone on the HR or hiring teams if the company has them. Don't overthink it, this is a super simple/reasonable ask and not something they will be annoyed about.

No one is looking for a formal job description of what your duties were, directly from the last employer, because it's way too much.  You wouldn't include every detail of a job description on a resume, just the same, because it's way too much.
Describe your normal, recurring duties and include any duties that might resonate with the person who's going to read the job description.   Demonstrate your college-level ability to summarize important facts.

Thanks for your answer! I was hoping that something like that would be enought but they specificly asking for a job description that is issued and certified by the employer.

Your original post didn't state that.  But if you can't get one, then you'll have to improvise.

edited thanks for pointing it out.
